# How to logout user correctly?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When user press the log out button he logged out and just see the login page again. But here's the problem he can log in again but can't navigate to the register page. What I should saying, I dont use Stream and will not use it.
Normally user can switch between sig in and register page im doing this with toogleview.

Heres my onpressed logout button:

```
 onPressed:()async{

                          FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginScreen.route, (route) => true));

                          },
```

And that's the error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _LoginScreenState._buildSignupBtn.<anonymous closure> (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/authenticate/signin.dart:186:26)
#2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#0f596
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(290.3, 560.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(211.6, 4.3)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

And here's where exceptions is I think :

```
Widget _buildSignupBtn() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        widget.toogleView();
      },
      //onTap: () => print('Sign Up Button Pressed'),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Don\'t have an Account? ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Sign Up',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
 Future<String> signIN(String email, String password) async {
    try {

  (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email.trim(), password: password,)).user?.emailVerified;

        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
 Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginScreen.route, (route) => true));
```

but make sure user is correctly signin

Comment: hmm still not working . I updated my post so you can see my sign in method.

Comment: What I should say it was running until I create a new page where I send the user if the register. it shows a message like this: PLEASE CHECK YOUR EMAIL ACCOUNT. And if they verify there mail they get automatically inside homepage. And since then when user sign out it shows this error. And before I had a future method for sign out and now just this method that you see .